# Cant add rows to data source due to identity conflict

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have a simple VS 2012 C# form with a data grid control bound to a binding source.  The SQL Server data source that this is bound to has an identity column (ID) that is also the primary key.

In the data set properties for this ID field, I have AutoIncrement = true,  AutoIncrement Seed = -1 (default) and AutoIncrementStep = -1 (default)

I cannot save a new row to the database.

If I add a new record using the tool strip, clear the ID field, then click the save icon I get this exception:  “Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table xxxx  when IDENTITY INSERT is set to off”.   If I leave the auto generated value of “-1” in the field, I get the same exception.

The code attached to the save button:

```
private void tblClassificationBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        this.Validate();
        this.tblClassificationBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.exportComplianceSISVTDataSet);
    }
```

Executing the last step results in the exception.

Some forum respondents recommend setting IDENTITY INSERT to “ON” as a workaround but many advise against this.

Comment: Where do you get these `default` values? AutoincrementSeed should be 0 and AutoincrementStep = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe you are binding the data from Sql server table. Set the IDENTITY property in the SQL Server Engine itself.That is on your table in the Server. 
>   Set the Seed to 1 and Increment to 1.
>   More on Identity: [Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
>
> [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97893/3)

Comment: Thanks.   I have the following set on the SQL Server side for this field: IsIdentity = Yes, Identity Increment = 1,  Identity Seed = 1.

Comment: Yes, thats the correct way.Then you need not set these properties again on the code file.

Comment: So, should I set AutoIncrement to false?  I tried that and it didn't help.  I should also mention that when I first added this data table to my project, I didn't have the ID field properly setup in SQL server.  I made it a primary key and identity later on.

Comment: Yup you do no need all those things like -  AutoIncrement = true, AutoIncrement Seed = -1 (default) and AutoIncrementStep = -1 (default). Now that you have the IsIdentity field set on the SQL Server.

Comment: Also check my updated answer. I have created a small demo which will help you understand it better.

Comment: Thanks for info.  I'm still unable to save a new record.  I'm going to try to make a new project/form/connection and see if it still misbehaves.       Update:  this worked.  with no changes on the server side.

Comment: Good luck. Do post in if you face any difficulties. Nice. You can mark the answer as Useful if it helped you.

Comment: I found the problem.   My project has a tableAdapter with an INSERT command.  The insert command included the ID field:      `INSERT INTO tblClassification
                         (ID, Find_No, Item_Number, Item_Description,..... ` 
      Removing ID from the insert command solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem. Setting Identity_Insert to ON for the table did not change the error, and created inconsistent behaviour in SQL Server Management Studio. When inserting records with the identity field defined, records were apparently inserted successfully but could not be seen in results from a select statement.

I solved the problem by changing the Update and Insert statements defined in the InitAdapter function in DataSetDesigner.cs  to exclude the Identity field. An example is shown below, where ID is the Identity field for the Update command.

`//this._adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = @"UPDATE [dbo].[Stopwords] SET [ID] = @ID, [Stopword] = @Stopword, [DateAdded] = @DateAdded WHERE (([ID] = @Original_ID) AND ([Stopword] = @Original_Stopword) AND ((@IsNull_DateAdded = 1 AND [DateAdded] IS NULL) OR ([DateAdded] = @Original_DateAdded)));
//SELECT ID, Stopword, DateAdded FROM Stopwords WHERE (Stopword = @Stopword)";
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = @"UPDATE [dbo].[Stopwords] SET  [Stopword] = @Stopword, [DateAdded] = @DateAdded WHERE (([ID] = @Original_ID) AND ([Stopword] = @Original_Stopword) AND ((@IsNull_DateAdded = 1 AND [DateAdded] IS NULL) OR ([DateAdded] = @Original_DateAdded)));
            SELECT ID, Stopword, DateAdded FROM Stopwords WHERE (Stopword = @Stopword)";`

As these changes are in autogenerated code, they will need to be reapplied if the dataset code is regenerated.